# Opamp creating a DC offset at high frequencies

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

I am measuring a 4th order filter that consists in the cascade connection of two biquadratic Rauch sections.

All my measurements went well except when I try to measure signals with high frequency (4 kHz.) Then the measurement "gains" a negative DC offset.

Is this because of some internal capacitances of the opamp?

Comment: Similar to mushroom syndrome, you are keeping us in the dark about Gain , f, Q and GBW with schematic and real measurements. - a better quality question has details and values

Comment: DC shift sounds like the result of clipping, perhaps at an internal node. Reduce input level until the offset disappears.

Comment: **Show us a schematic**.  Be sure to include the correct op-amp part numbers, and the amplitudes of your signals.  You're encountering some nonlinear phenomenon -- that devil is always in the details.

Comment: Did you see what happens when you reduce the amplitude of your input signals?  If it's from some nonlinear phenomenon then it'll be amplitude sensitive, and almost certainly the DC offset will reduce in amplitude faster than the input amplitude is reduced, at least over some range of input amplitudes.

Comment: It's quite possible that your interim stage is asymmetrically clipping - check earlier stage outputs. It's happened to me before and the big no-no is putting the high-Q stage first in line.

Comment: four hours without a schematic – sadly voting to close as in need of crucial detail :( sad, I think this might have been interesting!